# Ruby on Rails - specific case for Enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

These are from Ruby on Rails Document. (https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.4.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [ :active, :archived ]
end

# conversation.update! status: 0
conversation.active!
conversation.active? # => true
conversation.status  # => "active"
```

But if

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum reason: [ "not like", "need other" ]
end
```

In this case, `conversation.not_like?` can work if not how can I check?

Comment: You can by invoking the method using `public_send()`(`Conversation.public_send('not like')`) , but that would make it look ugly, no?

Comment: In that case, it seems better to move the reasons to a new table.

Comment: @SebastianPalma maybe just change it to underline. This might help you too: https://naturaily.com/blog/ruby-on-rails-enum

Comment: I guess you are trying to use the enum configuration as the display values. I don't think it's intended for that, you should use one-word strings or symbols and then use a helper method to display the correct string using the status value as a key.

Comment: We could propose something like that @MayraNavarro, but seeing that he's adding enum values for `reason` like "not" makes me doubt. Also because the support for negative scopes was added to Rails 6, things like that wouldn't be necessary anymore (and yes, I do see the documentation points to Rails v5.2).

Comment: What's wrong with `enum reason: [ :not_like, :need_other ]`?

Comment: This feels like a "doctor, it hurts when I do this" question ;) As suggested above, my advice would be to use `[ :not_like, :need_other ]`. Although it's *possible* to use spaces in the enum, it makes the code unnecessarily awkward.